# 47degrees AndroidSwipeList only receives move events every second touch

Tags: android, motionevent

I'm using the 47degrees android swipe list view 
https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

I have all the files copied into my Eclipse project unchanged.

I have the listview setup in xml

```
<com.company.appname.swipe.SwipeListView
            xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/home_list_view"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            swipe:swipeFrontView="@id/swipelist_frontview"
            swipe:swipeBackView="@id/swipelist_backview"
            swipe:swipeActionLeft="reveal"
            swipe:swipeActionRight="reveal"
            swipe:swipeMode="both"
            swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="false"
            swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="false"
            swipe:swipeAnimationTime="300"
            swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="100dp"
            swipe:swipeOffsetRight="0dp"
            />
```

I have setup the SwipeListView in code

```
SwipeListViewTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeListViewTouchListener(mListView, R.id.swipelist_frontview, R.id.swipelist_backview);
    touchListener.resetItems();
    mListView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

When I try to swipe an list item, the top view begins sliding away for a second then stops part way (say 10% on average but may vary slightly depending on the speed of the swipe). So it is stuck there in that position. The second time I try to swipe it, it scrolls smoothly away.

Note: It pauses every second time I touch an item - but it doesn't have to be the same item. For example, I could begin to swipe one row which will stop, then I could scroll either the same row or a different one and it will be smooth.

On investigation, I noticed the first attempt at swiping throws and `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event followed by a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event. The second time there is a `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` followed by a `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` followed by a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` (So the first time there is no `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`)

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I did not work with 47degrees AndroidSwipeList, but implement from [http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/] which is working fine in my case... have a look at that...

Comment: I have incorporated swipe listivew in my project but I dont have any problems can you post more code

Comment: Hi @Dittimon How you are managing swiped items when scrolling listView? because here I am also setting  swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="false" but in my case when I scroll listview swipedlistitem changing position. How you are managing this. Is there any method for managing this? Can you please post your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that changing the listview swipemode property to

`swipe:swipeMode="none"`

fixes my particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used swipe listview in my project and I am not facing any problems. The only difference I see in your code and mine is touchListener.resetItems();
I used swipe listener not touchlistener.

```
listViewCalendar
            .setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {

                @Override
                public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onListChanged() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onMove(int position, float x) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartOpen(int position, int action,
                        boolean right) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right) {



                }

                @Override
                public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
                    // 
                }

                @Override
                public void onClickBackView(int position) {
                    // Log.d("swipe", 
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) {

                }

            });

    listViewCalendar.setOffsetLeft((width - convertDpToPixel(115)));
    listViewCalendar.setSwipeMode(SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_LEFT);
    listViewCalendar.setSwipeActionLeft(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL);
    listViewCalendar.setOffsetLeft(width - convertDpToPixel(120f));
    listViewCalendar.setAnimationTime(75);
```

and heres my xml.

```
<com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/listViewCalendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonNewEntry"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
    swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
    swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
    swipe:swipeMode="both" >
</com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView>
```

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: `Hi @Illegal Argument I am also using com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView in my project. I am facing one problem when using 47 degree SwipeListView i.e., In my project I don't want to Close swiped items when scrolling listview so for that I set swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="false" in my xml. When I used this swiped list item changing position. Ex : If I swipe on 3rd item and I scrolled my listview swiping showing on 5t item so, how to manage this one in my project?`

Comment: @Rajesh SwipeListView extends listview so it reuses the views. That means if the opened list is outside the screen boundary it loses its opened state. You could save the state of the opened position in another array and could programmatically open it in your getView method of your adapter. It would be better if you ask a new question